# Coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $f(f(x))$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Let $f\left( x \right) = x + {x^2} + {x^4} + {x^8} + {x^{16}} + {x^{32}}+ ..$, then the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $f(f(x))$ is _____.

My approach is as follow

$f\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right) = f\left( x \right) + {\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)^2} + {\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)^4} + {\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)^8} + ..$

Let $T = f\left( x \right);U = {\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)^2};V = {\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)^4};W = {\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)^8}$

Let the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $T $ is zero

Taking U

${\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)^2} = {\left( {x + {x^2} + {x^4} + {x^8} + ..} \right)^2}$

Hence the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in  $U$ is $2x^{10}$ hence $2$

For $V$ and $W$ it is getting complicated hence any short cut or easy method to solve it

Comment: Hint: Binary expand the exponent.

Comment: What is Binary Expand

Comment: $\left( {x + {x^2} + {x^4} + {x^8} +\cdots} \right)+ \left( {x + {x^2} + {x^4} + {x^8} +\cdots} \right)^2 +\left( {x + {x^2} + {x^4} +\cdots} \right)^4 + \left( {x + {x^2} \cdots} \right)^8+\cdots$ has all the terms you need to look at $x^{10}$

Comment: Henry's hint is the basic idea. To use it efficiently you may first want to justfiy, why it suffices to look for the appropriate terms in the expansions of $(x+x^2+x^4+x^8)^2$, $(x+x^2+x^4)^4$ and $(x+x^2)^8$. You seem to have figured out the first of these already (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do the computation explicitly, then check with the engine.
It is enough to work in the field of polynomials in $\Bbb Q[x]$ taken modulo (the ideal generated by) $x^{11}$. We are composing polynomial functions $f,g$ that map $0$ to $0$, $f(0)=0$, $g(0)=0$, and there is a small computation to be done to show that changing either $f$, or $g$ (or both) by elements of the ideal $(x^{11})$ lead to the same result for $f\circ g$ before and after the change(s).

---

Lef now $f$ be $f=x+x^2+x^4+x^8+O(x^{11})$. Then, as in the OP and in the comments,
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(f(x))
&= f(x) + f(x)^2 + f(x)^4 + f(x)^8 + O(x^{11})\ ,
\\
f(x) &= x\Big(1+x+x^3+x^7\Big) + O(x^{11}) 
\\
f(x)^2 &= x^2\Big(1+x+x^3+x^7\Big)^2 + O(x^{11})
\\
&=x^2\Big(1+x^2+x^6 \ + \ 2x+2x^3+2x^7\ + \ 2x^4+2x^8\Big) + O(x^{11})\\
&=x^2\Big(1 + 2x + x^2 + 2x^3 + 2x^4 + x^6 + 2x^7 + 2x^8\Big) + O(x^{11})
\\
f(x)^4 &= (f(x)^2)^2\\
&=x^4\Big(1 + 2x + x^2 + 2x^3 + 2x^4 + x^6\Big)^2 + O(x^{11})\\
&=x^4\Big(1 + 4x^2 + x^4 + 4x^6\ + \ 4x+ 2x^2 + 4x^3 + 4x^4+2x^6\\
&\qquad + 4x^3 + 8x^4 + 8x^5 \ + \ 4x^5 + 4x^6\Big) + O(x^{11})\\
&=x^4\Big(1 + 4x + 6x^2 + 8x^3 + 13x^4 +  12x^5 + 10x^6\Big) + O(x^{11})
\\
f(x)^8 &= (f(x)^4)^2\\
&=x^8\Big(1 + 4x + 6x^2\Big)^2 +O(x^{11})\\
&=x^8\Big(1 + 16x^2 \ + \ 8x + 12 x^2\Big)^2 +O(x^{11})\\
&=x^8\Big(1 + 8x + 28x^2 \Big)^2 +O(x^{11})\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can extract the coefficient of $x^{10}$ from $f\circ f=f+f^2+f^4+f^8$, it is
$$
0 + 2 + 10 + 28=40\ .
$$

---

Well, i typed the above to show it can be easily done with bare hands.
However, if there is no structure found in there, then the solution is a computation (not an insight, in its essence), so why not use the engine for this task? Here are some ways to get the result in [sage](https://www.sagemath.org). Dialogues with the sage interpreter are shown, the dialogues are easily translated in a human, mathematical language, an advantage of sage (and of many other computer algebra systems..).

```
sage: R.<x> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=11)
sage: f = x + x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + O(x^11)
sage: f^2 + O(x^11)
x^2 + 2*x^3 + x^4 + 2*x^5 + 2*x^6 + x^8 + 2*x^9 + 2*x^10 + O(x^11)
sage: f^4 + O(x^11)
x^4 + 4*x^5 + 6*x^6 + 8*x^7 + 13*x^8 + 12*x^9 + 10*x^10 + O(x^11)
sage: f^8 + O(x^11)
x^8 + 8*x^9 + 28*x^10 + O(x^11)
sage: f + f^2 + f^4 + f^8 + O(x^11)
x + 2*x^2 + 2*x^3 + 3*x^4 + 6*x^5 + 8*x^6 + 8*x^7 + 16*x^8 + 22*x^9 + 40*x^10 + O(x^11)
```

Of course, the one-liner is also possible (after introducing the ring `R`)...

```
sage: f(f(x)) + O(x^11)
x + 2*x^2 + 2*x^3 + 3*x^4 + 6*x^5 + 8*x^6 + 8*x^7 + 16*x^8 + 22*x^9 + 40*x^10 + O(x^11)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's replace $10$ with a lower number, $5$, and illustrate the role of partitions in the result.

Only $f+f^2+f^4$ contributes to the coefficient of $x^5$. The $f$ term has none, of course.

The $f^2=f\cdot f$ term contributes a coefficient of $2$ from $x^1\cdot x^4$ and $x^4\cdot x^1$. Note that we get two terms because one contribution has $x^4$ from the first factor and the other has the $x^4$ factor coming from the second $f$ factor. Ordering of the partitions is important.

The $f^4$ term contributes a coefficient of $4$ which comes from $x^2\cdot x^3$ and $x^3\cdot x^2$ in the square of $f^2$. We get a contribution of $4$ here because the $x^3$ factor from $f^2$ had a coefficient of $2$ in $f^2$, which in turn came from $x^1\cdot x^2$ and $x^2\cdot x^1$ in the square of $f$.

So, the total of six terms in $x^5$, therefore a coefficient of $6$, came from the following partitions:

$5 = 1+4$ (from $f^2$)

$5 = 4+1$ (from $f^2$)

$5 = (1+1)+(1+2)$ (from $f^4$, with the parentheses showing the separate inputs to $f^4$ from $f^2$)

$5 = (1+1)+(2+1)$ (from $f^4$)

$5 = (1+2)+(1+1)$ (from $f^4$)

$5 = (2+1)+(1+1)$ (from $f^4$)

In other words:

- We picked partitions into powers of $2$, corresponding to the powers of $x$ in $f$.
- We picked those partitions where the number of terms is also a power of $2$, from the powers of $f$ you use in the outer function evaluation.
- For each partitioning satisfying the criteria above, we count all the distinguishable orderings.

Now try this partition scheme using $10$ as the input. There could be $1,2,4,$ or $8$ powers of $2$ in the partition, and for each partition that has different powers of $2$ there will be multiple orderings to count as we saw with the $x^5$ coefficient above.

> We have $8+2$ with $2$ orderings, $4+4+1+1$ with six orderings, $4+2+2+2$ with four orderings, and $2+2+1+1+1+1+1+1$ with $28$ orderings. Thus the coeficient of $x^{10}$ will be $40$.

The entire series begins as

$x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+6x^5+8x^6+8x^7+16x^8+22x^9+\text{[spoiler]}x^{10}+...$

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$f(f(x))=f(x)+f(x)^2+f(x)^4+f(x)^8+f(x)^{16}+\ldots$$
To find the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in this expansion, note that the smallest power of $f(x)^k$ for some $k$ is $x^k$.

Hence, to find the coefficient of $x^{10}$, we only need to consider
$$f(x)+f(x)^2+f(x)^4+f(x)^8$$
The coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $f(x)^k$ represents the number of solutions to
$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i=10$$
Where $a_i$ are integral powers of $2$.

We can systematically find these solutions using the binary representation of $10_{10}=1010_2$

If we are a little hand wavy with how we use binary representation, we can say that $10_{10}$
$$=1010_2$$
$$=210_2=1002_2$$
$$=130_2=202_2$$
Note that the expressions in the $i^\text{th}$ line represent the different ways to represent $10$ as a sum of $i+1$ integral powers of $2$ e.g. in the second line we have $210_2\implies 10=4+4+2$. We created the expressions in a line by recursively taking the expressions from the previous line and splitting a single power of $2$ in half.

We then have to account for permutations. Clearly $f(x)$ has no coefficient of $x^{10}$

The coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $f(x)^2$ is the number of permutations of $\{8,2\}$, which is $2!=\boxed{2}$.

The coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $f(x)^4$ is the number of permutations of $\{4,2,2,2\}$ and $\{4,4,1,1\}$, which is $\frac{4!}{3!}+\frac{4!}{2!2!}=\boxed{10}$.

The coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $f(x)^8$ is not as easily found using the recursive method we used before. However, it is easily found that the only way to express $10$ as the sum of $8$ powers of $2$ is $1+1+1+1+1+1+2+2$. There are $\frac{8!}{6!2!}=\boxed{28}$ permutations of this.

Hence, the total coefficient of $x^{10}$ is $2+10+28=\boxed{40}$

Answer (score 0):

For a polynomial

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n x^n$$

you find coefficient at $x^n$ as

$$c_n=\frac1{n!}f^{(n)}(f(0))$$

Now if you have a composite function $f(g(x))$ there is a well-known expression, Faà di Bruno's formula, which can be reduced to something simpler for your case.

In general if $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ and $g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n x^n$ then

$$f(g(x))=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n x^n$$

where

$$c_n=\sum_{i \in P_n}^{\infty}a_k\prod_{i=1}^{k}b_{i_k}$$

$$P_n=\{(i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_k) : 1 \leq k \leq n, \sum_{m=1}^{k} i_m=n \}$$

Applied to your case

$$c_{10}=\sum_{i \in P_{10}}^{\infty}a_k\prod_{i=1}^{k}a_{i_k}$$

$$P_{10}=\{(i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_k) : 1 \leq k \leq 10, \sum_{m=1}^{k} i_m=10 \}$$

But all your $a_n=0$ unless $n=2^m$ when $a_n=1$

Which is to say in how many ways you can uniquely represent $10$ as a sum of $1,2,4,8$ using $1,2,4,8$ terms.

That counting or similar you cannot avoid.

Answer (score -2):

To cut it short, for $x^{10}$ to appear in $f(x)^n$, you just need to have some $2^k$'s add up to 10. It doesn't necessarily require binary expansions.

Comment: Manually I have solved it but it is very cumbersome hence I decided to post this question so that someone can suggest me short cut method

Comment: You have the right idea, but there is more to it. Will $8+2$ work? Will $2+8$ give an additional contribution just because the ordering is different? What if you tried $4+2+2+1+1$ with five terms, will that work? You need a lot more subtle analysis to get upvotes.